# J2EE session expiry setting in Minutes and Seconds

Tags: session, tomcat, web.xml, session-timeout

I have a requirement to set the session expiry of my j2ee application as 4 Minute 30 Seconds.

As far as I know, session config section allows only minutes .

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        [Minute]
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

My question is, is it possible to enter decimal values like 4.5 (Equivalent to 4 Miute 30 Seconds)?

```
  <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            4.5
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, I had to accept the fact that only integers are allowed under 
`session-timeout` tag . If at all if session expiry to be set in seconds, then only way left is to control it through Java.

To Answer my question, **it is NOT possible to set session-expiry by seconds through web.xml**

Answer (score 0):

[Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1395925167_9273967315a3e4ca9c602cdb06177b1f) states the below

> The default time out period for sessions is defined by the servlet
>   container and can  be obtained via the getMaxInactiveInterval method
>   of the HttpSession interface.  This time out can be changed by the
>   Developer using the setMaxInactiveInterval  method of the HttpSession
>   interface. The time out periods used by these methods  are defined in
>   seconds

And so you should be able to specify the session-timout using setMaxInactiveInterval method.